# How to export a csv without header in Power BI Paginated Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

Is there any way of turning off the header/s for a CSV export in a Paginated Report on the Power BI Service?

I'm using Power BI Report Builder v15.7, but I know this might be irrelevant because this functionality should actually reside in the Power BI Service.

I have 5 tablixes in my report each with their individual Dataset.

I removed the headers of each tablix and my Output on the Power BI Service looks as following:

[image: Output]

So, it's showing correctly, but when I export it to CSV, the headers appear. (I removed sensitive information in the screenshot)

Your assistance will be much appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably need to add a new render format to the config file. See this post for more details https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2019/04/24/ssrs-how-to-export-a-csv-without-header-and-more/

Comment: @AlanSchofield I tried this, but it doesn't work. Firstly because Power BI Report Builder is like SSRS, but there is no Reporting Services installed on my machine, so I cannot install/add the additional extension. Hence my question subject refers to Power BI Report Builder...